# Free shipping method title showing twice

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, magento2.2.4, free-shipping

I am using magento **version 2.2.4.**

My free shipping method showing twice on checkout page like below image

[image]

All other methods name showing only once. How can i show free shipping title once ?

Comment: I think you have set Title and Method name same check into sales -> shipping methods -> your shipping method tab

Comment: @Hit's i have tried with different name but showing both name

Comment: Ohke make sure you have cleared cache and try once with re-deploy and static content deploy.

Comment: @Hit's Yes, tried but still showing both name and title